# EXT JS how come the cellmodel are not editable?

Tags: extjs

```
    Ext.define('RouteFareModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
        {name: 'Rate_ID', type: 'number'}, 
        {name: 'Route_Fare' , type: 'int'},
        'From_LocationName',
        'To_LocationName',
        'From_LocationID',
        'To_LocationID',
        'from_name',
        'to_name',
        'Route_ID',
        'Normal_Rate',
        'Discounted_Rate']
    });

    var RouteFareStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        model: 'RouteFareModel',
        storeId: 'RouteFareStore',
        autoLoad: false,
        sorters: [{
                    property: 'Route_Fare',
                    direction: 'ASC'
                }],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'get-routefare.php',
            api: {
                    create: 'insert-routeseq.php',
                    //read: 'http://visual04/ModuleGestion/php/Pays.php?action=read',
                    update: 'update-routeseq.php',
                    //destroy: 'http://visual04/ModuleGestion/php/Pays.php?action=destroy'
                },
            actionMethods: 'POST',
            baseParams: {
                    _id : 0,
                },  
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                idProperty: '_id'
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json',
                id: '_id'

             }
        }
    });

var cellEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 1
    });

Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyGridPanelRouteFare', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    id:'MyGridPanelRouteFare',
    alias: 'widget.mygridpanelroutefare',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    height: window.innerHeight,
    width: window.innerWidth/3,
    title: 'Route Fare Setting',
     selModel: {
            selType: 'cellmodel'
        },
    plugins: [cellEditing],
    store: RouteFareStore,
    columns: [
        {   
            xtype:'gridcolumn',
            width: 120,
            dataIndex: 'from_name',
            text: 'From Location'
        },
        {
            xtype:'gridcolumn',
            width: 120,
            dataIndex: 'to_name',
            text: 'To Location'
        },
        {
            xtype:'gridcolumn',
            width: 80,
            dataIndex: 'Normal_Rate',
            text: 'Normal Rate'
        },
        {
            xtype:'gridcolumn',
            width: 80,
            dataIndex: 'Discounted_Rate',
            text: 'Discount Rate'
        }
    ],
    dockedItems: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            dock: 'top',
            height: 30,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    id:'cmbFareRouteID',
                    width: 191,
                    store: RouteNameStore,
                    valueField : "_id",
                    displayField : "Route_Code",
                    fieldLabel: 'Route Code',
                    labelWidth: 70,
                    editable: false,
                    queryMode: 'local',  
                    listeners: {
                                    select: function( combo, records, eOpts ) {
                                    console.log("Combo selected _id : "+records[0].get('_id'));
                                    RouteFareStore.load({
                                                params:{
                                                    _id: records[0].get('_id')
                                                }
                                            });
                                    }
                                }
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    cls: '',
                    id: 'BtnFareCmbRefresh',
                    width: 65,
                    icon: '',
                    iconCls: 'refresh',
                    text: 'Refresh'

                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            dock: 'top',
            height: 30,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    cls: '',
                    id: 'BtnRouteFareSave',
                    width: 65,
                    icon: '',
                    iconCls: 'save',
                    text: 'Save'
                },              
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    cls: '',
                    id: 'BtnRouteFareRefresh',
                    width: 65,
                    icon: '',
                    iconCls: 'refresh',
                    text: 'Refresh'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]   
})
```

i have add
`var cellEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1
        });`

but the grid cell still not able to editable. why?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
            xtype:'gridcolumn',
            width: 80,
            dataIndex: 'Normal_Rate',
            text: 'Normal Rate',
            field: {
                xtype: 'numberfield',
                allowBlank: false,
                minValue: 0,
                maxValue: 1000
            }
        },
```

must insert `field: {}` , then the cellmodel able to editable already.

Comment: `field` is deprecated since 4.0.5. Use an [editor](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-editor) instead.

Comment: @MolecularMan what is the different with `editor:` and `field`, look similiar

Comment: `field` is an alias for `editor`. But `field` is deprecated (not supported anymore and eventualy it will be removed). So it is better to use `editor` instead.